# Growth per month MDX query

Tags: sql, xml, ssas, mdx, measure

I need to write the following query in MDX:

> The rental amount growth per month (include previous month) for each South America country
>   existing in the database (i.e., Argentina, Bolivia, Brazil, Chile, Colombia, Ecuador, French Guiana,
>   Paraguay, Peru, and Venezuela).

What I have so far is ( which I think has the correct strategy, but could be wrong )

```
WITH SET [South America] AS {Customer.Country.Argentina,
                            Customer.Country.Bolivia,
                            Customer.Country.Brazil,
                            Customer.Country.Chile,
                            Customer.Country.Colombia,
                            Customer.Country.Ecuador,
                            Customer.Country.[French Guiana],
                            Customer.Country.Paraguay,
                            Customer.Country.Peru,
                            Customer.Country.Venezuela}
MEMBER Measures.[Previous Month] AS Time.Month.CurrentMember.PrevMember
MEMBER Measures.[Payment Amount Growth] AS Measures.[Payment Amount] - Measures.[Previous Month]

SELECT  {Measures.[Payment Amount],
        Measures.[Previous Month],
        Measures.[Payment Amount Growth]} ON COLUMNS,
        [South America] ON ROWS

FROM Rentals
```

[MDX query and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Of47.png)

but as you can see, the previous month column is not being correctly calculated, it's empty. What am I missing?

[This is my xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHu8V.png)

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Managed to fix it. I was missing a way to show each month for each country. The fixed code is

```
WITH SET [South America] AS {Customer.Country.Argentina,
                            Customer.Country.Bolivia,
                            Customer.Country.Brazil,
                            Customer.Country.Chile,
                            Customer.Country.Colombia,
                            Customer.Country.Ecuador,
                            Customer.Country.[French Guiana],
                            Customer.Country.Paraguay,
                            Customer.Country.Peru,
                            Customer.Country.Venezuela}
MEMBER Measures.[Previous Month] AS Time.Month.CurrentMember.PrevMember
MEMBER Measures.[Payment Amount Growth] AS Measures.[Payment Amount] - Measures.[Previous Month]
SELECT {Measures.[Payment Amount],
Measures.[Previous Month],
Measures.[Payment Amount Growth]} ON COLUMNS,
[South America] * Time.Month.Members ON ROWS
FROM Rentals
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the following code

> MEMBER Measures.[Previous Month] AS
>   Time.Month.CurrentMember.PrevMember

to

```
MEMBER Measures.[Previous Month] AS 
(Time.Month.CurrentMember.PrevMember,Measures.[Payment Amount])
```